# Proximal Gradient Descent for Online Portfolio Selection

Tags: convex-optimization, machine-learning, gradient-descent, proximal-operators

I am going over [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/14697688.2017.1357831?journalCode=rquf20) on transaction costs optimisation for online portfolio selection and am having trouble with the proof of Proposition 4.2. Specifically, they write
\begin{align*}
 \tilde{\mathbf{b}}_{t+1}={\arg\min}_{\tilde{\mathbf{b}}}f(\tilde{\mathbf{b}})+\lambda\Omega(\tilde{\mathbf{b}})
\end{align*}
where $f$ is a differentiable convex function and $\Omega$ is the L1 norm.
They then claim that a closed form can be found by solving the following
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\tilde{\mathbf{b}}_{t+\frac{1}{2}}=\arg\min_{\tilde{\mathbf{b}}}f(\tilde{\mathbf{b}})\\
\tilde{\mathbf{b}}_{t+1}=\arg\min_{\tilde{\mathbf{b}}}\frac{1}{2}\lVert\tilde{\mathbf{b}}-\tilde{\mathbf{b}}_{t+\frac{1}{2}}\rVert_2^2+\eta_{t+\frac{1}{2}} \Omega(\tilde{\mathbf{b}})
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
They find the minimum of $f$ directly and use the proximal operator of the L1 norm to find a closed form for $\tilde{\mathbf{b}}_{t+1}$.
However, $t$ has nothing to do with iterations in this context and I don't see where gradient descent comes in (they say that the formulation was solved using Proximal Gradient Descent).
Is it the case that the proximal projection of the minimiser of $f$ is the minimiser of $f+\lambda\Omega$?

Furthermore, the optimisation problem above was already a linear approximation to the original one (Eq 6 in the paper). Are the updates they provide actually the solution to the TCO optimisation problem as claimed?

What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated!